# How to read three consecutive integers from stdin in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I want to read an input like `12 34 56` into three integers using Haskell.

For a single integer, one might use `myInteger <- readLn`. But for this case, I have not found any solution, except the one of first reading a line, then replacing all spaces with `,`, (using something like:

```
spaceToCommas str =
  let repl ' ' = ','
      repl  c =   c
  in map repl str
```

) and then calling `read '[' ++ str ++ ']'` which feels very hackish. Also, it does not allow me to state that I want to read *three* integers, it will attempt to read *any* amount of integers from stdin.

There has to be a better way.

Note that I would like a solution that does *not* rely on external packages. Using e.g. Parsec is of course great, but this simple example should not require the use of a full-fledged Parser Combinator framework, right?

Comment: Why not just call `readLn` 3 times in a do-block? Or use a map with side effects, map over a length-3 range, and call `readLn` inside the function. That would return a list of 3 ints.

Comment: Do you want to read 3 integers from a single line? Input is usually line-buffered - what if there are 4 integers on the single line?  What if there are only 2?

Comment: Oh, you want to read a single line? Why not just read that in then split on spaces?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, from a single line. If they are on multiple lines indeed your solution is easy and perfect.

Comment: Keep in mind you *never* read 3 integers; you *always* read one string. That string then needs to be parsed, which can range from trivial (if you are only expecting a single value of a type with a `Read` instance) to complex.

Comment: You write an IO action that reads one Integer and run it three times. That is how such problems are solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about converting the string like:

```
convert :: Read a => String -> [a]
convert = map read . words
```

`words` splits the given string into a list of strings (the "words") and then we perform a `read` on every element using `map`.

and for instance use it like:

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let [a,b,c] = convert line :: [Int] in putStrLn (show (c,a,b))
```

or if you for instance want to read the first three elements and don't care about the rest (yes this apparently requires *super*-creativity skills):

```
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let (a:b:c:_) = convert line :: [Int] in putStrLn (show (c,a,b))
```

I here returned a tuple that is rotated one place to the right to show parsing is done.

Comment: This doesn't read 3 integers from stdin, this simply grabs a line, tries to read it all, and fails with a pattern match error if there aren't exactly three. ("Also, it does not allow me to state that I want to read three integers, it will attempt to read any amount of integers from stdin.")

Comment: @user2407038: no it does not per se tries to read it all since `map` is lazy (and `f x` on an element of `map` is lazy as well), and furthermore with a tiny bit of *creativity* you could of course implement scenarios with two, four or an arbitrary amount of integers :).

Comment: How to use this properly in a pattern match? When trying to use `case convert line of`, I always get a `*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)`

Comment: The problem I was encountering was related to something else in my code